# How do I retrieve the WiFi key from Netgear assistant software?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, passwords

I am attempting to set up an additional computer on an office WiFi, but do not know the WiFi key.

There is a computer already connected to the WiFi which uses the Netgear WD111v2 wireless assistant software to manage the connection, but the WiFi key has asterisks hiding the characters.

How can I retrieve this key?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get access to the wireless key is to access the config page of the router. This page contains all the information and settings for the router including the wireless key. Usually this page is located at 192.168.1.1. The page may be located somewhere else, if you post up the model we should be able to find out for you. Once you are viewing the router config page, it should be relatively easy to get the wireless key.